# Where are the receiving and sending address descriptions stored?

Tags: wallet, receiving, sending

Are the sending and receiving address descriptions stored in the wallet file, or as some other file managed by the Bitcoin client app?

If I move or copy my wallet to a new installation of the Bitcoin client, will I still have my descriptions for my sending/receiving addresses available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, all of those are stored in the wallet.dat file. I myself have successfully migrated the wallet file to a new computer and have the addresses and descriptions intact.